# Why is my frame empty?

Tags: java, swing, frame

i tried for 2 hours to make a JEditorPane with a Scrollbar and i am about to give up!

This is part of my code:

```
    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    URL helpURL = GUIMain.class
            .getResource("/resources/einleitungstext1.html");
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    try {
        editorPane.setPage(helpURL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + helpURL);
    }
    editorPane.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
    editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    editorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    editorScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(main.screenWidth-200, main.screenHeight-200));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    this.add(editorScrollPane, c);
    this.setVisible(true);
```

When i do this.add(editorScrollPane,c) the frame is empty, but when i do this.add(editorPane, c) the panel is showing. Even with this.add(new JLabel("test"),c) the frame is empty.

Where is my error?

Thank you

P.S. I can't post the whole code because it is pretty big.

Comment: What class is this in?  What does it inherit from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The editor pane loads it contents in the background, this can mean that by the time the container is ready to laid out, the contents hasn't yet been loaded
2. The layout manager you are using and the constraints you have provided mean that it will use the preferred size of the scroll pane, which may not be adequate to meet the needs of the content (this is feature of the scroll pane, this is the way it's designed).

Either supply constraints to the `GridBagLayout` that encourage to use more of the available space or a layout manager that doesn't rely on the preferred size of the component (like `BorderLayout`)

[image]

```
public class TestLayout18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout18();
    }

    public TestLayout18() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
                try {
                    editorPane.setPage(new URL("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL");
                }
                editorPane.setEditable(false);
                JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
                frame.add(editorScrollPane);

                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a preferred size on the editorPane.  The scrollPane is looking for that for its viewport size.  You may want to set a minimum size on the frame as well.

Comment: When i set a preferred size on the editorPane nothing changes. The frame is maximised anyways. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: The viewport generally won't care about the preferred size of it's content, that's the point, instead it will use (if available) information provided by the `Scrollable` interface.  If you REALLY want to follow this line of thought, you'd be better creating a customised version of the editor that implements the `Scrollable` interface and return an appropriate value from `Scrollable#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` instead - but that's a lot of work when a few tweaks to or a different layout manager would solve the issues